# RuntimeError: This event loop is already running sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'create_dp_pool' was never awaited

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to set per server custom prefixes in Discord.py with PostgreSQL and asyncpg
I watched a video that is 1 years old so maybe thats why that doesn't work any more so i would be appreciate any help

This is my code in main.py

```
   import discord
    import os
    from discord.ext import commands
    import datetime
    import asyncio
    import random
    import json
    import asyncpg
    
    from discord.ext.commands import bot, Bot
    
    TOKEN = ''
    
    DEFAULT_PREFIX = "."
    
    
    async def get_prefix(bot, message):
        if not message.guild:
            return commands.when_mentioned(DEFAULT_PREFIX)(bot, message)
    
        prefix = await client.db.fetch('SELECT prefix FROM guilds WHERE guild.id = $1', message.guild.id)
        if len(prefix) == 0:
            await client.db.execute('INSERT INTO guilds("guild_id) VALUES ($1, $2)', message.guild.id, DEFAULT_PREFIX)
            prefix = DEFAULT_PREFIX
        else:
            prefix = prefix[0].get("prefix")
        return commands.when_mentioned_or(prefix)(bot,message)
    
    
    
    
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, intents=intents)
    
    
    async def create_dp_pool():
        client.db = await asyncpg.create_pool(database='name', user='postgres', password='')
        client.db = await asyncpg.create_pool(dsn='postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/name')
        print('Connection Successful')
    
    
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online)
        print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    
        await client.load_extension('cogs.cog')
        await client.load_extension('cogs.commandsforbot')
        await client.load_extension('cogs.moder')
    
    
    @client.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        guild = client.get_guild(1016358118982176772)
        channel = guild.get_channel(1018637868752703588)
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Community")
        await channel.send(f'Welcome to the server {member.mention} !')
        await member.add_roles(role)
    
    
    @client.command(aliases=['setpre'])
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def setprefix(ctx, new_prefix):
        await client.db.execute('UPDATE guilds SET prefix = $1 WHERE "guild_id" = $2', new_prefix, ctx.guild.id)
        await ctx.send("Prefix updated!")
    
    async def run_until_complete():
        async with client:
            client.loop.run_until_complete(create_dp_pool())
    
    
    asyncio.run(run_until_complete())
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

And i get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\unfge\Desktop\DISCORD BOT\main.py", line 73, in 
> asyncio.run(run_until_complete())   File "C:\Users\unfge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py",
> line 44, in run
> return loop.run_until_complete(main)   File "C:\Users\unfge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 646, in run_until_complete
> return future.result()   File "C:\Users\unfge\Desktop\DISCORD BOT\main.py", line 70, in run_until_complete
> client.loop.run_until_complete(create_dp_pool())   File "C:\Users\unfge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 622, in run_until_complete
> self._check_running()   File "C:\Users\unfge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 582, in _check_running
> raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running') RuntimeError: This event loop is already running sys:1:
> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'create_dp_pool' was never awaited

Comment: Try with `client.loop.run_until_complete(create_dp_pool)` without calling the method `()`

Comment: Then i get this


    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running